# DatabaseContext seed never completing

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is a long shot because there is so much custom code, but hopefully it is something simple.

I have this **DatabaseInitializer** class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Our Database initialsizer, which inherits CreateDatabaseIfNotExists. We could use DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges or DropCreateDatabaseAlways as well.
/// </summary>
public class DatabaseInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<DatabaseContext>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to insert our data upon initialization
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">Our DbConext</param>
    protected override void Seed(DatabaseContext context)
    {

        // Create our User
        CreateUser();

        // Seed
        base.Seed(context);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Private method which creates the user
    /// </summary>
    private void CreateUser()
    {

        // Create our unit of work
        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<DatabaseContext>();

        // Create our user service
        var service = new UserService<User>(unitOfWork, true, true);

        // Get our current date
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        // Map the user model out
        var user = new User()
        {
            UserName = "j***@*****.co.uk",
            Email = "j***@*****.co.uk",
            DateCreated = now,
            DateModified = now,
            LastLoginDate = now
        };

        // Run our task
        var task = Task.Run(async () => { 

            // Create our user
            await service.CreateAsync(user, "********");

            // Save the changes to our DbSet
            await unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        });

        // Wait for the async task to complete
        task.Wait();            
    }
}
```

Now the problem is, that it never seems to complete.
I am thinking it might be because of the async tasks, but I can't be sure.
I know there is no a lot to go on, but like I said I hope that it is something simple because showing you how my UnitOfWork class works along with my UserService would be a lot of code. Rest assured that they have worked fine in other projects.

**UnitOfWork**

This is what makes up my **UnitOfWork** class:

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : DbContext, new()
{
    private readonly DbContext context;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> repositories;

    public DbContext Context { get { return this.context; } }

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        this.context = new TContext();
        repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
            return repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepository<TEntity>;

        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(context);

        repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);

        return repository;
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await this.context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            ex.Entries.First().Reload();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's wise to create a new `DatabaseContext` in your `UnitOfWork` (at least that's what I suppose happens there) while `Seed()` runs. I guess this will call the initializer again, ad infinitum. Can't you pass the `context` from `Seed()`?

Comment: You should definitely call `context.SaveChanges()` on the same `DatabaseContext` instance. What is the implementation of your `UnitOfWork<T>`?

Comment: You should use the passed context variable for seeding but you're creating a new one in your UoW, I am assuming. Why not keep things simple and use the context and it's db sets directly for seeding?

Comment: can't use the context directly because the password is hashed in the user service.

Comment: updated my question to show my UnitOfWork class

Comment: What does `service.CreateAsync` does? Does it commit changes to the database?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you need to use the same datacontext.

Add a constructor to your `UnitOfWork<TContext>` class that can take an existing context as parameter:

```
public UnitOfWork(TContext context)
{
    this.context = context;
    repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
}
```

Then in you CreateUser method:

```
private void Createuser(DatabaseContext context)
{
    var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork<DatabaseContext>(context);
    ...
}
```